# Cross the Mexicali Border in a Taxi I get in the USA

Tags: usa, borders, mexico, taxis

Has anyone crossed the border in Calexcio/Mexicali in a taxi they picked up in the US?

I have heard that this is possible but I have never actually seen it in practice. I am in the process of finding a place to live in Mexico and it would be nice to move some personal effects via taxi. Someone told me that some taxis will cross the border and take you where you want. Where would I pick up these taxis? Has anyone actually done this?

Comment: I really doubt that a taxi is going to wait at the border for hours. I am near certain the border guards would be most unhappy with this.

Comment: @JamesAMohler Uh . . . FYI, the Calexico border crossing is far from a sleepy little outpost with guards standing next to the taxis. The cities on either side of the border have about half-million to a million people each with thousands crossing the border 24 hours a day. I'm sure the guards don't care about taxis waiting there, they probably don't even see the taxis from inside the large border admin buildings.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

For example, [Getting To Mexicali](http://mexicalimedicalguide.com/mexicali/getting-to-mexicali/) has a final sentence:

> While there are taxis that will take you across the border, it is only
>   a 5 minute walk and you can catch a taxi on the other side of the
>   border.

So for most people, doing the walk makes sense, but for you with your stuff, it does appear to be possible.

[MexicaliMaryann](http://mexicalimaryann.com/2011/02/28/how-safe-is-mexicali-%E2%80%A6-and-mexico-part-3/#comment-14112) also comments on her site:

> If you take a taxi into Mexicali from the US side of the border, it
>   will cost about $60 more.

indicating once more that it is possible, for a price.

Comment: Well yes but where? I have seen the same sources you cite. That's where I got the idea for this. But having been to the border multiple times. I can tell you that it's not obvious/clear where these taxis are. So I'm sorry but I'm looking for more than just citations. I want to hear from people that have actually done this